# my slider revolution wont work properly after optimizing with WP Rocket

Tags: wordpress, optimization, plugins, pagespeed

I have optimized my WordPress website with WP Rocket and it has speeded up my website. but there's a problem with slider revolution.  it wont be loaded up fast and i have to refresh my page for it to get loaded.
I have disabled java script optimization but the problem steel remains.
I'm using BETheme, Elementor, Slider Revolution and Wp Rocket.

how should I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please insert the following into WP Rockets Delay JavaScript Execution and Load JavaScript Deferred field and see if it helps.

**in the Delay JavaScript Execution field:**

```
/jquery-?[0-9.]*(.min|.slim|.slim.min)?.js
/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js
/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/
setREVStartSize
rev_slider_
revslider_
```

**Then, in the Load JavaScript Deferred field, please enter the following exclusions:**

```
/jquery-?[0-9.]*(.min|.slim|.slim.min)?.js
/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js
```

Answer (score 2):

Do you have "Delay JavaScript execution" enabled in the WP Rocket file optimization? Try disabling that, clear the cache and I hope it will fix the issue.

Comment: Exactly that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, but there is another catch with jquery that need to be excluded in "Delay JavaScript execution"

```
/wp-content/plugins/revslider/public/assets/js/(.*)
```

Add this:

```
(?:wp-content|wp-includes)(.*)
/jquery-?[0-9.]*(.min|.slim|.slim.min)?.js
js-(before|after)
```

This will solve slow loading/before user click slider

Comment: Did you add both the path and your "code" below to the "Delay JavaScript execution" exceptions? I tried this, too, but Slider Revolution still won't load properly. 

Side note: I have also "Minimize JavaScript" and "Summarize JavaScript" activated. I also tried putting your paths in their exception fields, too, but it's not working though.

Answer (score -1):

All these optimization plugin do is combine js/css files into one single file which might cause conflict with plugins/website functionality. Try following:

1. Remove/delete the optimization plugin.
2. Delete cache files.
3. Hard refresh the page(Windows ctrl+F5) or check in incognito mode.